# How to use profiler in Zend Studio with command line (CLI)

Tags: php, eclipse, profiler, zend-studio, zend-debugger

I have PHP application using Zend Framework 1, MVC pattern.

I can run an PHP applications in CLI mode:

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php /pathToIndex/index.php -a moduleName.controllerName.actionName
```

I can debug an PHP application in CLI mode:

```
QUERY_STRING="start_debug=1&no_remote=1&debug_stop=1&debug_host=MYIP&debug_port=10137&debug_file_bp=pathToFile" /usr/local/php5/bin/php /pathToIndex/index.php -a moduleName.controllerName.actionName
```

The option Run -> Profile as -> CLI Application do not allow parameters.

How can I run profiler in CLI mode?